# micro ros agent connectivity issue

Tags: ros2, ros-humble, micro-ros

I'm working with an ESP32 module running Micro-ROS, and I need to connect it to a PC using Micro-ROS Agent. I've tried changing the agent IP from dynamic to static and disabling any firewalls that might be blocking the connection. The module successfully connects to Wi-Fi, ruling out any Wi-Fi issues, but it still isn't recognized by the Micro-ROS Agent. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
[image: a successful connection should have more lines after this as publishers and subscribers]

Answer (score 0):

you could check for the firewall first. You need to enable udp first